# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, spring, hibernate

Estoy armando un proyecto con Hibernate y Spring, y H2 como base de datos, pero cuando intento correrlo me sale este error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-25 19:21:53.257 ERROR 4919 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.dh.clinica.persistence.entities.Odontologo, at table: turno, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(odontologo)]
```

Fui a la entidad Odontologo pero no encuentro dónde está el problema. Probé agregando la anotación @Table y @SequenceGenerator.

También intenté agregando "spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
" a application.properties y en el pom añadiendo las dependencias de Hibernate Core, pero nada. Si alguien pudiera guiarme.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.dh.clinica.persistence.entities.Odontologo, at table: turno, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(odontologo)]

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.dh.clinica.persistence.entities.Odontologo, at table: turno, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(odontologo)]
```

Les comparto el código de la entidad:

```
package com.dh.clinica.persistence.entities;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table
public class Odontologo {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "odon_sequence", sequenceName = "odon_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "odon_sequence")
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @Column
    private String apellido;
    @Column
    private Integer matricula;

    public Odontologo() {
    }

    public Odontologo(Integer id, String nombre, String apellido, Integer matricula) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public Odontologo(String nombre, String apellido, Integer matricula) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public Integer getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(Integer matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
}
```

La entidad Turno

```
package com.dh.clinica.persistence.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table
public class Turno {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "turno_sequence", sequenceName = "turno_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "turno_sequence")
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private Paciente paciente;
    @Column
    private Odontologo odontologo;
    @Column
    private Date fecha;

    public Turno() {
    }

    public Turno(Integer id, Paciente paciente, Odontologo odontologo, Date fecha) {
        this.id = id;
        this.paciente = paciente;
        this.odontologo = odontologo;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Turno(Paciente paciente, Odontologo odontologo, Date fecha) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
        this.odontologo = odontologo;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Paciente getPaciente() {
        return paciente;
    }

    public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
    }

    public Odontologo getOdontologo() {
        return odontologo;
    }

    public void setOdontologo(Odontologo odontologo) {
        this.odontologo = odontologo;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }
}
```

El código del Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dh.clinica</groupId>
    <artifactId>clinica-odontologica</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>clinica-odontologica</name>
    <description>clinica-odontologica</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.212</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Y el application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:clinica_dh
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

server.port=8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Odontolo y Paciente se refieren a foreign keys hacia otras tablas, por tanto deberías utilizar la anotación `@JoinColumn`. Te dejo un enlace donde se amplía información sobre la anotación [aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column)